# IIS 530 3 3 file system error on FTP Isolation

Tags: iis, permissions, ftp

I've been struggling with this issue for the whole week. In the past I've set up a lot of FTP servers on IIS with no major issues. But now I'm facing this and I don't know how to proceed.

I have a new VM instance in Google Cloud Platform running a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter OS with IIS 10. And I created the FTP site (With user Isolation using virtual directories) As I use to do with these servers. (I create the FTP Site, then LocalUser virtual directory and inside the folders named exactly the same as the user who will use them. Also, the physical path has all the permissions for that user - IIS_USERS and IUSR too -, and the authorization rule allowing access)

But it doesn't work, FTP client always throws the 530 error (With: Home directory inaccessible). I've checked all the authorization rules and permissions and everything seems good.

Checking the logs I found a detailed error code, the full code is 530 3 3. Looking at the docs it says that error # 3 is: "File system returned an error."... And I don't know what could it be.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter, I solved it using procmon.

I'll share my learnings about this issue just if someone in the future hits again with "530 User cannot log in, Home directory inaccessible" on IIS 10 / Windows Server 2019 and everything seems to be well:

1. What will guide you to the light is `Procmon` use it and you'll find whats going on.
2. In my case, when I set up all the virtual directories I created `LocalUser` folder (as it is written in all documentation about FTP isolation). But apparently in IIS 10 / windows server 2019. It doesn't use `LocalUser` as a wildcard for the local user accessing to the path. It has to be THE EXACT SAME NAME as the server (Using `Procmon` I noticed that it was looking for a path called just the same as my Server -e.g. EDD_SERVER - and of course, that path didn't existed - Actually, procmon result was: "PATH NOT FOUND" -)
3. So, I renamed the virtual directory on the FTP site from `LocalUser` to `EDD_SERVER` (the name of my server) and it worked like a charm.

I just don't understand why LocalUser isn't working anymore.

Hope it helps someone, kind regards.

Comment: based on "Procmon " tool, I ended up to create a directory link in "C:\inetpub\vhosts\Servers\7\localuser" using the tool "mklink", check this https://superuser.com/a/1004787

Comment: Amazing, this saved me going mad. NOTE THERE IS A GOTCHA - if you computer name is more than 15 characters, just use the FIRST FIFTEEN CHARACTERS

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same issue with a new Server 2019 / IIS10 setup and this thread helped me

In my case, as the server was domain joined, the virtual server under the FTP root had to be the name of the domain (netbios name).  I found this out via procmon.  After renaming everything worked great